# Merge multiple DataFrames with identical column names and different number of rows

Tags: python, pandas

Given multiple dataframes, df1, df2, df3, df4...with identical columns names, differing only in the number of rows, like so:

```
Data columns (total 4 columns):
Name               23 non-null object
Team               23 non-null object
Games              23 non-null int64
Average(Points)    23 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1), int64(1), object(2)
memory usage: 864.0+ bytes
None (23, 4)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 69 entries, 0 to 68
Data columns (total 4 columns):
Name               69 non-null object
Team               69 non-null object
Games              69 non-null int64
Average(Points)    69 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1), int64(1), object(2)
```

Do I merge, concat ou join

```
pdList = [df1, df2, df3, df4]
```

How so?

Answer (score 0):

```
pdList = df1.append([df2, df3, df4])
```